# Onclick function triggered with page load instead of clicks

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have been searching about this issue with onclick triggers that actually trigger with page/window load, but could find a solution for the following.

I need to the id of the latest clicked button, so I did this:

```
 var lastButtonId = [];//to get the latest Id
// then the onclick statements:
 document.getElementById('traffBut').onclick = sendButtonId('traffButton');
 document.getElementById('convBut').onclick = sendButtonId('convBut');
 document.getElementById('revBut').onclick = sendButtonId('revBut');
 document.getElementById('tranBut').onclick = sendButtonId('tranBut');
//Below the funstion to get the last Id:
 function sendButtonId (clikedButton)
       {
        lastButtonId.splice (0,1,clikedButton);   
         console.log(lastButtonId);
       }
```

But the console shows the following on Page Load:
[Click here to see console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLQ9H.png)

I have tried different ways of doing this but can't get mu head around it,

I hope someone can give me a hint :)

Many thanks
J.

Comment: Why aren't you just sending the ID in the call to the function? IE `sendButtonId('traffBut');` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you must pass a *function* to the onclick attribute, and not a *function call*. I mean, you must not call the function you want to be called on click, but instead pass a reference to the function.

So, if you want to call sendButtonId, just write:

```
document.getElementById('traffBut').onclick = sendButtonId;
```

Though, as you want to add arguments to the function call, you must create a new function that will automatically apply this argument when called. It can be done using .bind, which returns a new function with the given parameters:

```
document.getElementById('traffBut').onclick = sendButtonId.bind(this, 'traffButton');
```

Comment: This worked, many thanks, will study more about the bind method :) and thanks again!